# Reviewer thinks there is no change in documentation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign, documentation, review-queues

If you add something like `<!-- language-all: php -->` at the beginning of a documentation example, reviewers see no difference. Example below:

[image]

One relevant change is here: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/129687

A bunch of edits I submitted to make content more readable were randomly rejected, because users thought I had not changed anything. It should be visible to users.

Without this, anytime someone post a change to make doc more readable with syntax highlighting, it will be randomly refused because a reviewer can not see the difference.

I hope it's clear enough; it's my first post (I guess) on META. I can edit if required.

*EDIT:* Some example of rejected edits:

- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/129678?filter-tags=laravel
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/129642?filter-tags=laravel
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/129645?filter-tags=laravel
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/129640?filter-tags=laravel
- etc.

Some reviewers uses a default comment, and some other actually write it's because there is no change.

*EDIT:* Maybe I will have fewer rejects with better summaries. Anyway, I think the differences are still not really visible.

Comment: There's very obviously a change there. I mean, we wouldn't just cross out the entire code block and re-add it for no reason. This visual cue should prompt a user to look at the side-by-side markdown option, which very clearly shows what was changed. If reviewers aren't doing this, then they're not reviewing properly.

Comment: "This visual cue should prompt a user to look at the side-by-side markdown option" Actually, they don't look : 50% of a dozen of submission I made were rejected for the exact reason "there is no change".

Comment: @rap-2-h Unfortunately by the same two users every time. We'll let them know they're Doing It Wrong™.

Comment: @Kendra Ok this one is still pending. But you could have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/129679?filter-tags=laravel http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/129678?filter-tags=laravel http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/129642?filter-tags=laravel http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/129645?filter-tags=laravel http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/129640?filter-tags=laravel etc.

Comment: @Kendra You are right, I edited my question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: From the list in your last comment, I don't see very good (or in some cases any) edit summaries. Be clear in your edit summary and the likelihood of bad reviews will go down (not much, since people are lazy, but some is better than none).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Ok thanks. I thought reviewers will understand before viewing a lot a "reject". You are right, I will add better summary. BTW I don't know why I'm downvoted here!

Comment: See [What is Meta?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) for information about downvotes on meta.

Comment: I was one of those. I honestly didn't notice that change. Thanks for the info anyhow, now know where to look in a similar situation.

Comment: I was expecting to see reviewers not reading a good and descriptive edit comment. But "*formatting*", or even no comment at all: seriously? You should at least *try* to help honest reviewers. Also: your question is tagged [feature-request], but otherwise it's complaining that reviewers are not attentive enough, which is partly your fault. Hence my downvote now. If you turn this into a feature request, I'll remove it, because that would be fine.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Ok, thanks. I edited my post yesterday to add "I will have fewer rejects with better summaries.". BTW, I'm not complaining about reviewers and I know it's partially my fault (and not their fault at all). I'm just saying **it's not visible for users** (I did not said: "users don't look"). In many other case, no comment is almost OK, because it's obvious to users you just changed fixed words. But in that case, it's not obvious because it's not visible. I will be more careful about my comments, but I think it could be *visually* improved.

Comment: @AndrasDeak side question: what do you want me to remove about "complaining about reviewers"? I can edit, but I'm not sure what part is about this subject (I think I'm not complaining but maybe something is unclear or too rude. I can edit!)

Comment: Meh, I don't know, maybe it's just me. I read your post and it came across more as "something's wrong people are rejecting edits" than "please make edits like this more visually obvious in review". But it might be fine as-is, I just wanted to respond to your question regarding downvotes.

Comment: @animuson I think a substantial number of users may just believe the behavior is a bug with the diff software. I've seen diff software go wrong several times before.

Comment: @animuson I agree with Goose. As a reviewer I thought perhaps the user had some wonky line endings changed or something. In Git for example it will do the whole remove/add thing if line endings change (or at least historically it did). I have rejected this scenario once thinking it was only a line ending change. It might be worth showing just the language line versus the content of the body?