# C++ documentation, rejected change

Tags: support, documentation, proposed-changes

I proposed a change that got [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/130217) in the C++ documentation file I/O page.

The change was small, only a link to the cppreference page of ofstream.
It got rejected with the following comment:

> Does not attempt to explain or illustrate the topic. It may be a request for improvement, a question, or something else unrelated to Documentation.

While this indeed does not further explain the topic, this seems like a small but helpful addition to people viewing it. I have seen similar links in other documentation so can someone explain why this addition is not helpful?

If this should be asked/ handled in another way links to that would be appreciated as well, but I honestly do not know what or where to look for.

Comment: I can easily imagine that a link to a "here is the *real* documentation you need" article is not terribly popular.  It completely defeats the point of writing that article in the first place :)  There might well not be any point to it, iostream does not exactly suffer from a lack of documentation, but certainly not what the author(s) had in mind.

Comment: I, and I think most people, look at Documentation to get some examples that you can quickly copy and change. If I then want to look at some other methods of the class I'll go to the cppreference.
I get if we just don't want any other sources to keep people on stackoverflow but I've seen similar links on other articles. Is there any concensus on this?

Answer (score -1):

A few observations:

1. It isn't immediately clear in review that the change is an added link. This has been fixed for the [suggested edit queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142919/suggested-edits-that-change-links-should-jump-out-and-punch-reviewers-in-the-fac) by forcing the Markdown diff view. We have this on our backlog to fix along with a [similar problem with HTML comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345097/reviewer-thinks-there-is-no-change-in-documentation).
2. The link itself is to a site that comes up fairly early in the Google results for ["ofstream"](https://www.google.com/search?q=ofstream). As far as I can tell, this isn't an official reference, so it's not entirely clear why you picked it. The change message isn't entirely clear either.

   Adding the link makes the page a tiny bit harder to read because of the distraction and potential for diversion. Maybe it's because I forgot most of what I've learned about C++, but the page linked to is incomprehensible to me.
3. None of the rejection reasons fit:

   [image: Documentation review rejection reasons]

   I guess I'd pick other and explain that the change did not improve the topic. (If, by chance, I thought you were promoting your own site, I guess I'd pick vandalism instead.) Getting these categories just right is going to take time. And then they will need to be adjusted as people find new ways to misunderstand them. (See also: [comment flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292011/drop-not-constructive-combine-noisy-reword-rude-and-other-comment-flag).)
4. You probably could have avoided your change being rejected by improving other parts of the topic.

In summary, we'll probably have some fixes for #1 and #3. But #4 is really the key to getting changes approved.